# Relationship field breaks window-height (jQuery) in Chrome

Tags: relationships, jquery

I can't figure this out. I have some simple javascript-code that uses the height of the window to do something. When I add a relationship-field to my code the window-height is wrong. It goes from 900px (for example) to 7000px (the whole document).

It's NOT about the added height (the added content is about 50x high), but suddenly jQuery seems to not understand the window-height anymore.

Even when I add a relationship-field tag as simple as this:

`{home_projects}
  test
{/home_projects}`

it fails. Weird thing is that Firefox doesn't have this issue. I'm also not getting any javascript-errors in the console.

Oh, btw, it's not the javascript function itself. The only thing I'm trying now is:

```
var w = $(window);
var h = w.height();
alert(h);
```

Adding the relationship-field code as written above breaks this code and says the window is about 9000px high. Removing it says the window is the height it should be. And again: only in Chrome.

Any thoughts? This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Maybe sharing the output of the html before and after adding the relationships tags would help us figure out your problem

Comment: Also, I don't think that this issue is one that should be in the ExpressionEngine stack exchange. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518436/jquery-height-problem-with-chrome